# How do I make a for loop that scans through JSON in F#

Tags: json, f#, json.net, f#-data

Using F# I am trying to scan through a JSON file and compare its arrays against a single array of (randomly generated) numbers. The formatting for the json is:

`{"1":[#,#,#,#,#],"2":[#,#,#,#,#],...}`

etc for 121 entries.  I'm currently trying Json.NET.  My problems are:

- How can I import a local file with Json.NET?
- How would I set about making a simple call of the json key that'd return it's array value that's fit to run it through a for loop?

Here is my code of how far I've gotten:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open Newtonsoft.Json

(*open FSharp.Data

type Provider = JsonProvider<"powernum.json">
let numbers = Provider.Load("powernum.json")

//numbers.``1`` gets me the array but can't scan through all the IDs with an iterating for loop
(*
if numbers.``3`` = [|29;30;41;48;64|] then
    printfn "True"
else printfn "False"
*)
(*numbers.JsonValue.Item "1" 
let test (a: int) = string a
let testPile = 
    for i = 1 to 10 do
    let goNum = numbers.JsonValue.Item (test i) 
    Console.Write goNum
    Console.WriteLine ""
testPile    // This works but is not usable for data comparison with an F# Array
*)
*)

let r = new StreamReader("\PATH\powernum.json")
let (json: string) = r.ReadToEnd();
let conv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> (json)

Console.WriteLine("{0}",conv)//where I'm stuck with Json.NET

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let rnd = Random()

    let numberGen = Set.empty.Add(rnd.Next(1,69)).Add(rnd.Next(1,69)).Add(rnd.Next(1,69)).Add(rnd.Next(1,69)).Add(rnd.Next(1,69)) |>Set.toArray |>Array.sort


    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore 
    0// return an integer exit code
```

Jsontocsharp.com renders invalid.

I've tried using F# Data but from what I've found it's impossible to make an iterating loop because I have to pull up the "key" with accents encapsulating the number to read it as an int like this ``` numbers.``1`` ```.It doesn't take variables. Tried another method while still using F# Data but it only works as a string that errors when I try to convert it.

For comparison this is the version I prototyped in python:

```py
import random
import json
with open('/PATH/powernum.json') as pnumbers:
    data = json.load(pnumbers)

#makes an array with the range of numbers
Valid_numbers =[]

for x in range(69):
    Valid_numbers.append(x+1)
generated = []

def pulledNumber():
    generated[:]=[]
    #adds numbers to the array from 0-4
    while len(generated) !=5:
        #takes a random number from the range of numbers
        generate_number = random.choice(Valid_numbers)
        #check if the two arrays have the same values
        if generate_number not in generated:
            #add to the array if values don't match
            generated.append(generate_number)
    generated.sort()
    return generated

pulledNumber()

for x, y in data.items():
    if generated not in y:
        print("Id: %s passed" % x)
    else:
        print("Id: %s failed" % x)
        pulledNumber()
        break

print (pulledNumber())
```

Comment: If you need to work with json. Read about [type providers in F#](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html).

Comment: @Wootiae - it's a little tricky to use `JsonProvider` when you have variable property names though, see [Can JsonProvider deserialise to a Generic.Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24182737/3744182).  If you know an easy way to do it, it would be cool if you added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f# is a statically typed language - we simply often don't notice because of its excellent type inferencing.  But when deserializing from a JSON file, before writing any code, it is useful to determine whether the JSON has a fixed schema, and if so, create or choose an appropriate data model to which the JSON can be mapped automatically.

In your case, your JSON looks like:

```
{
  "1": [29,30,41,48,64],
  "2": [29,320,441,548,11]
  // Additional items omitted
}
```

When you have here is a root object with variable property names whose values are always an array of integers.  As explained in the Newtonsoft documentation *[Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)*, such a JSON object can be deserialized to some `IDictionary<string, T>` for appropriate value type `T`.  And as explained in *[Deserialize a Collection](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)* a JSON array can be deserialized to a collection of an appropriate item type.

In f# we use [`Map<'Key,'Value>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-class-%5bfsharp%5d) to represent a dictionary, and [lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists) to represent a materialized list of statically typed values.  Thus your JSON corresponds to a

```
Map<string, int list>
```

Having determined an appropriate data model, introduce the following function to deserialize JSON from a file:

```ml
//https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm
let jsonFromFile<'T>(fileName : string, settings : JsonSerializerSettings) = 
    use streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName)
    use jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader)
    let serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings)
    serializer.Deserialize<'T>(jsonReader)
```

Now you can deserialize your JSON and filter the values for lists matching some

```ml
let fileName = "\PATH\powernum.json"

let requiredValues = [29;30;41;48;64] // Or whatever list of values you are looking for

let map = jsonFromFile<Map<string, int list>>(fileName, null)

let filteredMap = 
    map |> Map.toSeq
        |> Seq.filter (fun (key, value) -> requiredValues = value)
        |> Map.ofSeq

// Print results
filteredMap |> Map.iter (fun key value ->
   printf "Key = %A has matching list of values = %A\n" key value)
```

Which prints out

```
Key = "1" has matching list of values = [29; 30; 41; 48; 64]
```

Notes:

- Always be sure to dispose of [disposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable#remarks) resources such as `StreamReader` after you are done with them.  The [`use`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword) keyword ensures this happens automatically when the resource goes out of scope.
- If you would prefer to search for an *unordered set* of values, you can use [`set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.set-module-%5bfsharp%5d) instead of `list`:

  ```ml
  let requiredValues = set [64;29;30;41;48] // Or whatever set of values you are looking for

  let map = jsonFromFile<Map<string, Set<int>>>(fileName, null)

  let filteredMap = 
      map |> Map.toSeq
          |> Seq.filter (fun (key, value) -> requiredValues = value)
          |> Map.ofSeq
  ```
- As explained in *[Equality and Comparison Constraints in F#](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224073851/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx)* by Don Syme, both `list` and `set` support structural equality comparisons, which is why `requiredValues = value` checks that the collections have identical *contents*.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KvwAnR) for `list` and #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrwmai) for `set`.

Comment: @Tripmodo - If you are having troubles, try to share a [mcve] that reproduces your problem by forking one of the fiddles in my answer then modifying it to reproduce the problem.  Your original question didn't actually include sample JSON so maybe my data model doesn't match perfectly.

Comment: So far the map seems to be pulling up arrays that have a number in common with my array, along with some other random selections, but your example has enlightened me  a bit to using maps to solve the problem. Thanks for your help. I'll try to do some more research to get the results I want, but for getting json working and scannable, I'd call this problem solved.

Comment: @Tripmodo - Are you using a .Net array or an f# `list` to hold your numbers?  Structural equality comparison works for `set` and `list` but not non-f#-specific collections like arrays.  A [mcve] would go a long way towards clarifying your problem.

Comment: I converted mine to a list `val requiredValues : int list = [9; 18; 50; 63; 65]`  and the map gave me `val map : Map<string,int list> =
  map
    [("1", [1; 2; 3; 7; 39]); ("10", [18; 36; 45; 47; 69]);
     ("100", [2; 9; 17; 36; 67]); ("101", [9; 12; 15; 31; 60]);
     ("102", [12; 33; 54; 57; 60]); ("103", [23; 30; 35; 41; 57]);
     ("104", [35; 49; 50; 59; 66]); ("105", [14; 47; 54; 55; 68]);
     ("106", [16; 32; 35; 36; 46]); ...]` Not completely sure if this was the intended result, but I figure I'll use a list that matches one from the json and work my way up from there.